# Is there a means of telling a movieclip to tile/stretch to cover a a whole window

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I have a movieclip on its own layer, with the intention of using it as a background to all the other layers. It is simply a black square with the alpha at 60%. There must be a relatively simple way of telling this movieclip to either tile or stretch to cover the whole of any page it loads into.
Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can position the movieClip in the upper left hand cornder and then size it to the size of the stage like this:

```
box.x = 0;
box.y = 0;
box.width = stage.stageWidth;
box.height = stage.stageHeight;
```

This assumes your clip is called box

Comment: This seems to go part way to solving the problem, but rather than filling the stage the 'box' fills roughly a quarter of it.  Also, the final application for this is going to be in-browser over a web page, will the 'box' go to the browser window's x=0, y=0 because the stage I am working on is smaller than that.

Comment: you need to make sure your box has an upper left registration point. Also, if you want to fill the browser window you might need to do: stage.scaleMode = "noScale"; stage.align = "TL"; That will align the stage to the upper right hand side of the screen and prevent scaling.

Comment: The second suggestion for making sure the clip scales to the size of the browser window doesn't seem to work properly, the clip still limits itself to the size of the stage I used.

Comment: is your html setup to fill the page?